# R range distance - is there an existing function?

Tags: r, function, range, distance, difference

Very simple one here - does anyone know if there's an existing single function that returns the absolute distance between the range of a vector? i.e.:

```
tmp <- rnorm(100)
range(tmp) # -2.659657  2.853642
#This line:
range(tmp)[2] - range(tmp)[1] # 5.513299
```

Is there already something that just does that final line? I've looked for various things but it occurs to me that it might have a specific name in maths that I've not stumbled upon yet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [diff()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/diff) function:

```
diff(range(tmp)) # 5.513299
```